# Piping output to python from bash, script runs in background

Tags: python, bash

I'm using zbarcam to read barcodes, since zbarcam doesn't terminate automatically after reading a code.

Here's my main.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from config import *

while(1):
    os.system('clear')
    print "------Parking Sector 11----------"
    print "Select : "
    print """1. Scan Code\n2. Update Balance\n3. Exit\n"""

    choice = raw_input()

    if choice == '1':
        subprocess.call("./k.sh")
```

I'm using the following script to pipe its output to a python script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=/tmp/barcode.$$
zbarcam --raw /dev/video1 > $tmp &
pid=$!

# Sleep until file has content

while [[ ! -s $tmp ]] ; do
    sleep 1
done

kill $pid
cat $tmp | ./inout.py
```

The following is my inout.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import MySQLdb as db

con = db.connect(server, user, pwd, database)
cur = con.cursor()

reg = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
vtype = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
make = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

print reg, vtype, make

cur.execute("update local set bal=%s where regno=%s", (newbal, regno))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

The problem is this file is running in background as I'm not able to see the output of `print` (I know it's running because the database is being updated). Sometimes I would want to print certain statements for wrong code or something like that, how can I make this file run in terminal instead of background.

Comment: why cant you output the info messages to log file? and then monitor the logs

Comment: Because if the code is wrong the user would have to update his qrcode and run this again. He needs to be shown an error message for this.

Comment: you want a command line interaction for this? something like `raw_input` ?

Comment: Yes, I need the print statement to be displayed, but its not being displaying since the script is running in background.

Comment: after displaying the print statement, what is the flow ?

Comment: Nothing Happens, the print statement is not displayed, no terminal is launched.

Comment: I am talking hypothetically. I want to know the behavior you want. After showing the `print` statement, what should happen?

Comment: I'm using another main.py file which calls the bash script when scan is selected, after the `print` statement, this main.py should open again. The problem is main.py does open on exit, but the print statement doesn't display